# Adding external jars NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jboss, noclassdeffounderror

I have a problem when adding external jars to my project. I'm using `gradle` for building my project and deploy multiple wars on JBoss. I have added these external jars using `"dependencies { compile libraries }"` so these jars are inside war projects.

My project builds successfully but when I call a webservice I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS015594: Method invocation failed with exception: Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xml.security.Init.
```

This `org.apache.xml.security.Init` class is called from the class which is in the external jar file.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Where are your config files? Are you're putting the relative path, not absolute?

Comment: The jar of the lib you are refering to is listed in the WEB-INF/lib folder of the war file generated?

Comment: You are using Axis? What version of jboss?

Comment: @vkrausser, yes, after build necessary jar file is placed inside war archive under under WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: @AndreDuarte, which config files do you mean?

Comment: @FedericoSierra, no, I am not using Axis. My JBOSS version is 6.1.

Comment: put a copy of the jars to jboss\server\default\lib